# Quickblox sample code unauthorized

Tags: xcode, quickblox

I'm creating a chat app using [this Quickblox chat tutorial](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios). I downloaded a demo project and put my app details in AppDelegate.m. When I run the project I get an error message - unauthorized.

Why is this happening? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Chat application uses predefined demo user login & password.

If you put your app details - you also have to update your user demo user login & password. Go to admin panel and create a new user for example.